# не могу сохранить динамическую страницу на selenium python3

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

нужно сохранить динамическую страничку ютуба. Я скролю страницу до кона и использую метод
driver.page_source для записи в файл для дальнейшего парсинга но страничка сохраняется без подгруженных данных т.е только первые 10 видео!

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEjpJz-JIzzaO0KMF8HgAew/videos'
headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36",
        'x-youtube-client-name': '1',
        'x-youtube-client-version': '2.20200429.03.00',
        }
def get_source_html():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\youtube_parser\geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get(url=url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        h_prev = 0
        while True:
           with open("source-page.html","w",encoding='utf-8') as file:
            h = driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight + window.scrollY;')
            driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo(0,{h});')
            time.sleep(0.3)
            if h == h_prev:
                file.write(driver.page_source)
                break
            h_prev = h
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
def main():
    get_source_html()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Извините! бага нету. Я просто неправильно проверял файл на наличие подгруженных данных.